# Tkinter: update Text widget from variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a variable that is updated on a button click, and I want to show the variable's value in a Text widget, but I'm getting a blank every time despite checking that the variable is not empty.

I'm using a `StringVar` called `var` as a middle man but the result is still blank.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

var = None

def get_tags():
    tag_info={'hashtags':"Loading..."}
    var.set(str(tag_info.get('hashtags','')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.title("Tag Generator")
   var = StringVar(root)
   show_button = Button(root, text='Show',
          command=lambda: get_tags())
   show_button.grid(column=2,columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=5, row=num+1)

   result_text = Text(root)
   result_text.grid(column=0,columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, row=num+2, rowspan=4)
   result_text.insert('1.0',var.get())

   while True:
       time.sleep(0.01)
       root.update()
```

How can I show the contents of `var` in my Text widget?

**EDIT**:contents of my var variable:

```
var.get()
Out[86]: '.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n#cat #dog #catsofinstagram #cats #pet #dogsofinstagram #catlover #cute #love #dogs #pets #catstagram #instagood #puppy #kitty #animals #petstagram #dogstagram #gato #kitten #animal #instadog #catoftheday #doglover #cats_of_instagram #adorable #instagram #dogoftheday #instacat #meow '
```

(which is as expected/desired)

Comment: I added the necessary lines to your code to make it runnable and it seems like there is no problem. `var.get()` is adding text into the  `Text` widget it could've to do with `tag_info` try printing it to the console and check if it has any value or not?

Comment: `var.get()` run alone seems fine, I edited my question to demonstrate

Comment: I think the issue is that the contents of the Text widget doesn't update

Comment: We can't run your code, it has many problems.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for your enlightening comment. It appears I forgot to add the imports and initial declaration of `var`. I will edit my question accordingly and humbly beg your forgiveness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is not showing because the `var = ''`  at line `result_text.insert('1.0',var.get())`and you can't press the `Button` before `mainloop` so by putting the same line in function `get_tags()` should solve the issue.

But at this point I'm wonder why you even need `var`. If you're not using it for anything else then you should remove it and `insert` in the `Text` directly.

```
def get_tags():
    tag_info={'hashtags':"Loading..."}
    tag_info = my_file.get_tags()
    var.set(str(tag_info.get('hashtags','')))
    result_text.insert('1.0', var.get())
```

Comment: I added var because I had the same issue when I directly put the text in, and assumed it was a format issue

Comment: Do you want the text in a straight line? As the string have so many `\n` which trends text to go to next line..

Comment: No, that's normal for the expected output, and your fix here works perfectly